# Stopping NSOperationQueue when it is making changes to UI

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a custom NSObject class(Downloader) which uses NSOperationQueue to download images and as it downloads a image it is updated to Main class UI. Here the issue is I couldn't cancelOperations in downloader class when the downloading is happening. I guess the Main thread is held by NSOperationQueue call backs and when i try to call canceloperations it only responds once all the downloading is finished. Please provide me a break through into this...my heartily  thanks...

Comment: Did you implement the cancel test within your NSOperation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in AppDeledate property, for example

```
@property (readwrite) BOOL isOperationQueueMustHold;
```

and then, in you nsoperation cycle, add that code:

```
while (delegate.isOperationQueueMustHold == YES)
{
   sleep(1);
}
```

this will stop hard work while u UI will updated.